# CraftCMS Hosting in Australia?

Tags: server

Can anyone recommend a hosting company that can handle running CraftCMS based out of Australia?

I've tried contacting http://www.digitalpacific.com.au/ but they came back to me with this:

"I have had this reviewed by our technicians to ensure we recommend the correct solution. I have been advised that due to the "crypt() with BLOWFISH_CRYPT" requirement, we are unable to host this on a Business hosting plan."

Comment: FWIW, crypt() with BLOWFISH_CRYPT is guaranteed to be available in PHP 5.3+, which is Craft's minimum requirements. So if they're not running PHP 5.3, then you've got bigger problems to solve.

Comment: Hi @user3210210 and welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange! While hosting questions are important, they're considered off-topic for this site because they're open and subjective. (The help center [goes into detail about what's on-topic](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) if you're interested.) This is a great question, however, for a Friday Craft Chat or the Google+ site.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not in Australia, but I've seen Luke Holder (of Perth) [repeatedly mention Digital Ocean](https://plus.google.com/u/0/107146320975542982883/posts/QZSyJjbHyzJ). I've heard other folks describe having a good experience with Digital Ocean as well.

> [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/)

Comment: Putting perth on da map!